# I am following up as to

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

I spoke with an attorney on the phone yesterday and he said he would get back to me with regards a quote for the service I was requesting. I am writing a follow-up email to him today to see if he has the quote. Is the following sentence correct?

> Good afternoon! I'm following up as to the quote for the services I am requesting.

Or should I say:

> I'm following up on the quote for the services I am requesting.

Comment: Both are fine, but the shorter one (*"on the quote"*) is better, as it's more succinct.

Comment: Make sure to include the “Good afternoon” no matter which you say.